# using cd command and few other commands after ssh

Tags: shell-script, weblogic

I am trying to run 3 to 4 commands after doing ssh in a script.

can you please help me out with this. Since, it says, it cannot access the directory.

```
tfptools@tfpwltst01:TEF_PERU:tfptools> vi temporary.ksh
tfptools@tfpwltst01:TEF_PERU:tfptools> ./temporary.ksh
```

**ls: cannot access weblogic.*.log: No such file or directory
Connection to tfpwltst06 closed.**

This is the below command, I am trying to use to login to a server and do cd and then print all exception present there:

```
#ssh -t tfpabp12@tfpwltst06 /bin/sh -c '"cd ~/JEE/ABPProduct/logs/ABP-FULL/ABPServer && var=$(ls weblogic.*.log | tail -1) && cat $var | grep xception | sort | uniq -c | sort -n"'
ssh -t tfpabp12@tfpwltst06 /bin/sh -c '"cd ~/JEE/ABPProduct/logs/ABP-FULL/ABPServer && cat $(ls weblogic.*.log | tail -1)"'
```

Comment: Why are you using "-t" parameter? Furthermore, why don't you try to cat directly the file with the whole path instead of cd-ing before? Additionally, I also don't understand why you don't cat directly over the file name without using ls.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your comment, but I want to fetch the latest log, which has weblogic written in it (it is weblogic log). so, i have to do this. as cat is not working there for me.
I have tried ssh without -t and its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following command:

```
ssh tfpabp12@tfpwltst06 cat ~/JEE/ABPProduct/logs/ABP-FULL/ABPServer/weblogic*.log | tail -1
```

Comment: It's still not working. :(

cat: /tfpnfs/tfp/tfptools/JEE/ABPProduct/logs/ABP-FULL/ABPServer/weblogic*.log: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the output of "ls /tfpnfs/tfp/tfptools/JEE/ABPProduct/logs/ABP-FULL/ABPServer/‌" on tfpwltst06 server?

Comment: This below command, I modified and reran and I found logs within that directory:
ll JEE/ABPProduct/logs/ABP-FULL/ABPServer/


-rw-rw-r--. 1 tfpabp12 aimsys   615795 Jan  5 04:50 CMServer.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 tfpabp12 aimsys   174578 Jan  5 04:50 ABPAPIAuditLogInputParameters_20170105040922.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 tfpabp12 aimsys  4107132 Jan  5 04:51 ABPServer.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 tfpabp12 aimsys  6498183 Jan  5 04:53 JF.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 tfpabp12 aimsys   367376 Jan  5 04:53 weblogic.20170104_230514.log

Comment: Anyway, modified your command, you gave me previously and I got result, which is little near to my result:
ssh tfpabp12@tfpwltst06 "cat ~/JEE/ABPProduct/logs/ABP-FULL/ABPServer/weblogic*.log | grep RUNNING"

I want the latest log content printed on my screen and it should have error grep in it. output:
tfptools@tfpwltst01:TEF_PERU:tfptools> ./temporary.ksh
<Jan 4, 2017 1:06:09 PM PET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>
<Jan 4, 2017 11:12:22 PM PET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.>

Comment: Why do you grep RUNNING? Honestly I don't understand exactly what is the output you want.

Comment: It was just an example, that I took RUNNING there, you can take error, exception or, anything, but I need to proceed with that. 
Need to do ssh and then do cd and look for the latest weblogic log and then find the error in it. :(

Comment: Try with:  `$ logname="$(ssh tfpabp12@tfpwltst06 ls -rt ~/JEE/ABPProduct/logs/ABP-FULL/ABPServer/weblogic* | tail -1)" && ssh tfpabp12@tfpwltst06 grep -i error $logname`